# How do I restrict my application to show up in the "Open in..." menu on iOS for a specific document type

Tags: ios, share-extension

I need to restrict my application to show up for ppt file types.How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will get the 'kind' of file.

```
- (NSString *)humanReadableFileType:(NSString *)path
{
    NSString *kind = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
    LSCopyKindStringForURL((CFURLRef)url, (CFStringRef *)&kind);
    return kind ? [kind autorelease] : @"";
}
```

After that check it like that

```
if([kind isEqualToString:@"ppt"])
{

}
```

Source: http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2007/01/07/cocoa-snippet-finding-a-files-kind/#post-19